# php mysql не выполняется 2 запроса подряд

Tags: php, mysql, запрос

В php-скрипте идут два запроса:

```
$qe = mysql_query("INSERT INTO baob (arm,detk,ib) VALUES('$did',1,'$da')");
$qey= mysql_query("INSERT INTO baob (arm,detk,ib) VALUES('$arm',2,'$da')");
```

Первое выполняется, второе нет.

Если первый запрос закомментировать - выполняется второй.
Как заставить выполниться оба запроса?

Comment: А ошибки какие-то пишет?

Comment: нет, вообще никаких сообщений. Все данные выводятся на экран.

Comment: А не срабатывает ли какое ограничение? скажем, уникальность по полю ib...

Comment: Добавьте после каждой строки `echo mysql_error(); ` и посмотрите, что напишет. Ну и да, забудьте про расширение mysql и используйте mysqli или PDO

Comment: Может быть так? $qe = mysql_query("INSERT INTO baob (arm,detk,ib) VALUES('$did',1,'$da'), ('$arm',2,'$da')");

Comment: Ну начнем с того что mysql уже не используется, вместо него пишут mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно обязательно посмотреть, нет ли ошибок при выполнении запроса функцией mysql_error():

```
$did = "str1";
$da = "str2";
$arm = "str3";
$q1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO baob (arm,detk,ib) VALUES('$did',1,'$da')");
echo "Error query1: ".mysql_error()."; ";
$q2= mysql_query("INSERT INTO baob (arm,detk,ib) VALUES('$arm',2,'$da')");
echo "Error query2: ".mysql_error().". ";
```

P.S. И да, как писали выше - не используйте функции mysql_, вместо них нужно использовать mysqli_!

Answer (score 0):

Можно вставить несколько строк в эту таблицу одним запросом, для этого выполняем следующий запрос:

```
INSERT INTO users (username, birthdate) VALUES 
    ('Виталий','2018.02.15'), 
    ('Петр','2018.02.16'), 
    ('Николай','2018.02.17');
```

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте использовать класс [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) для работы с БД.

Приведу код в Объектно-ориентированном стиле. Также есть возможность использования того же кода в процедурном стиле.

Пример:

```
$connect = new mysqli(host,login,pass,db);
$connect->query("INSERT INTO baob (arm,detk,ib) VALUES ('$did',1,'$da'), ('$arm',2,'$da');");
$connect->close();
```

Перед этим, переменные

> $did, $da, $arm

следует экранировать: или методом *htmlspecialchars()*, если там будет передаваться **html**-разметка или так, если передаются просто значения:

```
$сonnect->real_escape_string($did);
$сonnect->real_escape_string($da);
$сonnect->real_escape_string($arm);
```

если нужно экранировать обычные значения. Это позволит избежать проблем с **sql-инъекциями**. Но даже это не всегда спасет. Более подробно описывается [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/148701/).

```
//Второй вариант:

$connect = new mysqli(host,login,pass,db);
$connect->query("INSERT INTO baob (arm,detk,ib) VALUES('$did',1,'$da')");
$connect->query("INSERT INTO baob (arm,detk,ib) VALUES('$arm',2,'$da')");
$connect->close();
```

Или с использованием *подготавливаемых* запросов:

```
$connect = new mysqli(host,login,pass,db);
$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO baob (arm,detk,ib) VALUES (?,1,?), (?,2,?);";
$stmt->bind_param('ssss',$did,$da,$arm,$da);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$connect->close();
```

Используемые методы: [*prepare()*](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php), [*bind_param()*](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php);

**UPD**. Добавлены советы по использованию первого варианта работы и ссылка на дополнительный материал.

Comment: Я бы первую часть ответа вообще убрал. 80% всех взломов сайтов из за подстановки переменных непосредственно в текст. не надо учить людей так делать. пусть сразу используют привязываемые переменные.

Comment: ня ;)

https://prowebmastering.ru/php-pdo-start.html